# Keeping database credentials secure in a PHP application

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on my first PHP application. Right now, I'm keeping my database connection details in constants in a config file outside of my root folder, as I read this is the most secure way to prevent people from getting your database credentials.

If I include that file into my PHP application, aren't those constants now visible everywhere in my code and isn't that still a bad thing? My personal idea to overcome this is just to create a database class, also store it outside of the root directory, and then put my credentials in private parameters. So it would be something like this:

```
class Db {

    private $host = 'host';
    private $dbname = 'dbname';
    private $username = 'username';
    private $password = 'password';

    private $connection;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->open_connection();
    }

    private function open_connection() {
        try {
            $this->connection = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname, $this->username, $this->password);
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }

}
```

And then I would just include this file instead, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone gets access to your PHP source files, you have bigger problems than your database login being found. Just saying.

I keep my DB credentials in a place that makes sense: in the function call that connects to the database.

Comment: But keeping the credentials in the function calls, can become very redundant, and makes it difficult to change them.

Comment: @Micah Um... There should only be one function call to connect to the database...

Comment: It depends on how massive your project is. If it's all in 1 file yeah you can connect once but if you're running a whole site... no. Well it could still work if you only had one database user, and one shared file.

Comment: @Micah Normal people have a `DB` class, or a `connect.php` file that gets included.

Comment: So in terms of code, that's about as far as I can take it for security, and my next step would be to make sure my web server is secure, is that correct?

Comment: That works as well, I think I might try that. What I did was create a function that would get the username passed to it, and then connect using the passwords that are stored in an ini file.

Answer (score 0):

That would add some security, but I'm not sure it'd be completely worth it. The reason you keep the config file outside of the root directory is to prevent clients from calling up the credentials on the web. It should be safe with your first method as long as the user has no way to execute their own PHP, which they shouldn't.

You should be more focused on making it more difficult if they have terminal access. You should lock down the files so only root can see them. Also disable outside DB access, block port 3306 in the firewall and disable Mysql networking. [Use this.](http://www.greensql.com/content/mysql-security-best-practices-hardening-mysql-tips) I hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: This certainly has some useful tips, but I think I would be somewhat limited in what I could do in a shared hosting account, would I not?

Comment: It all depends on the admins, however if the admins haven't done those things, you may want to consider someone else, unless they have a good reason. Also if you can't limit the permissions to root, make it so only your user can see it.